# npm ERR! tarball.destroy is not a function

Tags: node.js, reactjs, windows-10, npm-install, react-dom

Hi I'm having issue while installing react-dom module.

I'm able install other modules like react express modules, on windows 10. 64 bit machine

```
npm install react-dom
npm WARN package.json -panel-client@1.0.0 No description
npm WARN package.json -panel-client@1.0.0 No repository field.
npm WARN package.json -panel-client@1.0.0 No README data
npm WARN package.json -panel-client@1.0.0 No license field.
npm WARN retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: EBUSY: resource busy or locked, rename 'C:\Users\NOI-DE~1\AppData\Local\Temp\npm-3064-f12f714d\registry.npmjs.org\react-dom\-\react-dom-0.14.8.tgz.2090210803' -> 'C:\Users\NOI-DE~1\AppData\Local\Temp\npm-3064-f12f714d\registry.npmjs.org\react-dom\-\react-dom-0.14.8.tgz'
npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.10586
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "react-dom"
npm ERR! node v4.4.3
npm ERR! npm  v2.15.1

npm ERR! tarball.destroy is not a function
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>
npm WARN retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: EBUSY: resource busy or locked, rename 'C:\Users\NOI-DE~1\AppData\Local\Temp\npm-3064-f12f714d\registry.npmjs.org\react-dom\-\react-dom-0.14.8.tgz.2000813013' -> 'C:\Users\NOI-DE~1\AppData\Local\Temp\npm-3064-f12f714d\registry.npmjs.org\react-dom\-\react-dom-0.14.8.tgz'
```

Comment: Nodejs version v4.4.3

Comment: I am still getting the same error on npm install of restify . Any other means of solving this out ?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

yes It is caused by the anti-malware software

Comment: How do you know which software is causing the issue?

Comment: I've disabled my Antivirus. But it's not working. Any Solutions ? Here's the Question (Link)[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69947874/next-js-installation-error-npm-warn-tarball]

Answer (score 54):

We met the same issue in one Dell computer. Finally we found it was caused by the ByteFence Anti-malware software. After we uninstalled it, npm works.

Comment: How did you find out that, btw? just curious! they seem so unrelated issues

Comment: @Yao I've windows default antivirus software. I've tried to disable it then run it. But it's not working why ??

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue before. On removing anti-malware(ByteFence) it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 3):

I got this error when I was out of disk space.

Deleting my /root/dump files, and dropping a very large mongo db, then doing a server reboot fixed this issue for me.

Answer (score 3):

`sudo rm /tmp/* -R -f` solved my problem in arch linux.

Answer (score 2):

ByteFence create problem. uninstall and npm install worked fine.

Answer (score 2):

uninstall  or stop ByteFence and it will run

Answer (score 1):

I was using npm in dell machine. I met the same issue (tarball.destroy is not a function). At the time I had installed anti-malware software. Then I had uninstalled it, then npm working fine. This is my suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Reason  : anti-malware software

Try : uninstall "ByteFence" named application

Comment: in what way does that add anything new?

Comment: Can you add more explaination, as to why it would help ?

Answer (score 0):

Try: **npm cache clean**, if the issue exists try **renaming the folder** npm-3064-f12f714d in the mentioned path C:\Users\NOI-DE~1\AppData\Local\Temp\npm-3064-f12f714d for the issue mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

I had got the same error while installing angular/cli. On uninstalling the anti-malware on my Windows 10 machine worked as the trick, I was able to successfully install angular/cli.
The anti-malware in some ways restricts the installation of certain modules via npm.

Answer (score 0):

1. Make a new directory in C:\Users\AppData\Local with Temp2
2. Go to Environment variables
3. Change variable **TEMP** value = **%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Temp2**.
   Hope it works.

Answer (score 0):

I found mentioned folder (e.g 'npm-3064-f12f714d') **unmarked** as being readonly and I think that helped. The difference also was that I run command from cmd and earlier I did it from VS Code, but I think it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

This was truly caused by Anti-Malware software in my own case.

Answer (score 0):

Try disabling the antivirus and then run it. It worked for me.