# Difference between installing React.js and Node.js and Using Script tag for library

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am confused about React.js installation. I'am wondering what is better in development using React.js. The one that install using **Node.js npm** or the one that is using like this:
    `<script src="build/react.js"></script>
    <script src="build/react-dom.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-core@5.8.38/browser.min.js"></script>`

Can someone help me explain this because I really want to learn React.js.

[image: When I try installing react using Node cmd I get this error and I dont know why?]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error could be the result of an anti-virus interfering with the npm install.
 
Look here: [npm ERR! tarball.destroy is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36835882/npm-err-tarball-destroy-is-not-a-function)

Answer (score 2):

If you are installing via npm , then you can use webpack , browserify to create the bundle js which would contain all your modules plus react one.

You can write your code in ES6 and webpack/babel can transpile that to Es5.

If you include the script as shown below

```
<script src="build/react.js"></script>
    <script src="build/react-dom.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-core@5.8.38/browser.min.js"></script>
```

Then as your modules/js files get loaded it will be transpiled which would be time consuming , because you are doing that operation in browser.

Go for the npm one, commonjs style is now common format

Comment: I tried to make a project using npm but while i'm installing it on node cmd i get this error. See my edited post.