# npm -g install issue

Tags: node.js, npm

I am not able to install anything and also can't able to run any npm script form package.json

```
PS D:\Users\Subho> npm install -g json-server
npm WARN retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: EBUSY: resource busy or locked, rename 'D:\Users\Subho\AppData\
Local\Temp\npm-8508-54f2d409\registry.npmjs.org\basic-auth\-\basic-auth-1.1.0.tgz.3339144024' -> 'D:\Users\Subho\AppData
\Local\Temp\npm-8508-54f2d409\registry.npmjs.org\basic-auth\-\basic-auth-1.1.0.tgz'
npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.15063
npm ERR! argv "D:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "D:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "ins
tall" "-g" "json-server"
npm ERR! node v7.0.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.8

npm ERR! tarball.destroy is not a function
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>
```

Node -v
7.0.0
npm -v
3.10.8

Comment: This error is often caused by anti-virus or anti-malware software.  see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36835882/npm-err-tarball-destroy-is-not-a-function

Comment: Not anti virus I guess. There is some version problem. See https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/17931

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I have also posted this question on GitHub. The perfect solution is needed to upgrade the latest npm stable version.
Here is the GitHub issue link:
https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/17931